# Android USB debug

Tags: android, samsung-mobile

I have i9301 Samsung Galaxy S3 Neo. I could not enter the USB debugging mode. I enabled the USB debugging in the menu but when I connect the device to the PC it immediately fires up message saying that it connect via MTP which I can switch to PTP. There is no possibility to change it to the USB storage mode even if it is turned on in the developer options. There is also no context menu with USB options under "Storage" or other settings. Do I need to root my device somehow or even install some mod OS? Is there simpler way to make it USB Mass storage device?

Answer (score 2):

You need to enter into developer mode and enable usb debugging. Then you can plug in the USB cable in your phone and pc and optionally go into a command window and run "adb connect"

Edit: you can get into developer mode by hitting build number (found in the About phone section of settings) repeatedly

Comment: I did this. However it does not work. I have enabled USB debugging and whenever i connect my device to the PC it connects as MTP device and allow me to switch to the PTP device but not to the mass storage mode.

Comment: I tried what you suggested. Here is console output of my phone: 
`>adb connect`  
 *Usage: adb connect <host>:[<port>]*
`>stop adbd  
>start adbd  
>adb usb ` 
 *error: device not found*

Comment: Unfortunately it gives me a message *error: device not found* regardless if the device is connected or not to the USB cable. MTP mode works fine.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows PCs, you need to install a USB driver for Samsung as described [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html).

After this, you might need to restart the adb server:

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
```